Apache2 forward gunicorn socket error
I have a minimal hello world django app that I want to deploy to my server. Chatgpt told me to use Unix Domain Socket for better performance.
I managed to start my gunicorn service in a screen tty via:
gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind unix:/var/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock --error-logfile /var/log/myproject/gunicorn.error.log

And this is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myproject.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / unix:/var/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock|fcgi://localhost/
    ProxyPassReverse / unix:/var/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock|fcgi://localhost/

</VirtualHost>

But when I access http://myproject.mydomain.com with my browser, I got 503 error.
For debug purpose, I set the socket file permission as 777,changed file ownership group to deployers (containing ubuntu,www-data). I also tried to sudo -u www-data curl --unix-socket /var/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock http://localhost/ and got expected response.
Here is my apache error log.
[Sun Oct 06 15:07:19.512454 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 160756] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 06 15:07:19.512479 2024] [core:notice] [pid 160756] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 06 15:11:00.537321 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 160759] [client 127.0.0.1:37940] AH01068: Got bogus version 72
[Sun Oct 06 15:11:00.537367 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 160759] (22)Invalid argument: [client 127.0.0.1:37940] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :

Here is my gunicorn error log.
[2024-10-06 15:11:00 +0800] [161935] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 161935


Gunicorn does not support fastcgi. I should use http proxy instead.
The lines in apache site config should be
ProxyPass / unix:/var/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock|http://localhost/
ProxyPassReverse / unix:/var/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock|http://localhost/

